# how to define font style of embed tag in html

Tags: java, html, css, stylesheet

I was paused in the point of defining font-family in embed tag of html because i defined the Cssclass and  mentioned in the style tag too,but it doesn't change.

so I need a suggestion for changing font style in embed tag. In embed tag, content is uploaded by the admin panel simultaneously. We need to define the font style using css,is there any way to do that?

code

```
       <embed  src="result/Career.txt" class="auto-style4"  />
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I'm not sure what your question is. It seems to me, that you mis-interpret, what the `<embed>` tag is for. If you want to include a css style in a page, you need to use `<link>`. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Comment: Hi, Embed tag is used for displaying the objects

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Suggestion: Don't use `embed`, include the file on the server side.

Comment: We have upload a text (Notepad) file to Server through a portal.The Text file data need to display on a paragraph tag for a website . How will work . if you give any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php for this! and it can be embedded into your html file directly.

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents( "filename.php" );
?>
```

you can wrap your php statement in an html tag of your choice, then with css style the tag.

Comment: the question refers to html, not php